# How to ase RecyclerView Instead of ScrollView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

How can I use RecyclerView instead of ScrollView? ScrollView is giving me errors, so I want to use RecyclerView instead of ScrollView.

This is my first fragment layout code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?\>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/homeF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/androidbackground2"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

When I want to move from this layout to the layout below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?\>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/androidbackground2">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I got an error like this:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct
> child

I can't switch layout because of this ScrollView error. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code produces this error:

> This androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout should use android:layout_height="wrap_content"

That's resolved by using `wrap_content`, instead of `match_parent` for the height of the `ConstraintLayout`.

Secondly, there's no need to provide constraint attributes for the `ConstraintLayout`. The constraint attributes should be added in views that are children of a `ConstraintLayout`, in order for them to have an effect.

Thirdly, using a `ConstraintLayout` doesn't make much sense here. Try using a `LinearLayout` instead, like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Finally, using a `RecyclerView` isn't a solution that should be used instead of using a `ScrollView` and it shouldn't be used just to use its scrolling capabilities. You should use a `RecyclerView` in different cases, for example whenever you'd like to render a dynamic list of items. For more info you should read [the official doc](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview?gclid=CjwKCAiA9NGfBhBvEiwAq5vSyyWWoeGcH1P34BSd2erl23-wkGBgm4ukyrywLMwUe1e4lqeID8wB8RoClREQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).